# Adjoint of the derivative operator on $C([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $D \colon \operatorname{dom}(D) = C^1[0,1] \subseteq C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$
be the derivative unbounded operator $D(f) = f'$. 
Since $C^1$ is dense in $C$ we can define the adjoint operator 
$$D^* \colon \operatorname{dom}(D^*) \subseteq C[0,1]^* \to C[0,1]^*$$

We can identify $C[0,1]^*$ with the space of all bounded signed measures $M([0,1])$ and hence we can characterize $\operatorname{dom}(D^*)$ by the set of all bounded signed measures $\mu$ such that $$f \to \int_0^1 f'd\mu$$
is continuous. I want to use some kind of integration by parts but the only thing that I know is that $\mu$ is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure represented by the càdlàg with bounded variation function $$F(x) = \mu((0,x])$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: On a side note, I'd include the definition of càdlàg functions ([link to wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g)) - this is not a really widespread term.